# Difference betweeen analog and digital IC deisgn flow

Tags: digital-logic, analog

I tried to find the main differences but not too sure on what could be the main differences in analog and digital design flow. Apart from the circuit design and verifying your circuit level or test bench level design what should one be more concerned about for Analog and digital design ? Would be great if you guys share some light on the same !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really too broad to answer.  Our formal flow is the same as far as steps, but the outcomes are very different.  I do both analog and digital design, and they are very different because your constraints are very different.  Also, your goal is fundamentally different things.  For instance, in an analog design I spend most of my time trying to keep noise to a minimum so I am burning a lot of relative constant current.   In digital designs, I am more concerned about timing and clocks.  With subthreshold asynchronous FPGAs, I am most concerned about my completion trees being fast so I burn power there, and my other circuits never get above Vt.   The point:  they are all different and you are trying to do different things for the same medium.  This is also why you will find that courses are broken into analog VLSI, digital VLSI and RF VLSI.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know that they are pretty different but I just wanted to be sure on what the main emphasis would be on for both with respect to the design flow. Apart from the circuit level design what should one be more  concerned about for digital and analog was my main doubt and your answer explained it right I think.

Comment: If you want a feel for two flows, here's some things from my old class:  http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~degs/projects/simulate.hspice.html  http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~degs/projects/simulate.sos.html  The first is a digital simulation and setup and the second is simulating of the frequency dynamics of the very analog Second Order Section.

Comment: Sure I will definitelly have a look at it !